# "What you've been doing?" and "What have you been doing?" Are they both the correct way to ask?

Tags: present-perfect, questions, colloquial-language

Can I ask someone: "What you've been doing?" with proper intonation? Will it be considered ok the same as "What have you been doing?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to ask someone about their recent activities is "What have you been doing?".

However, if you were to ask somebody that, but they didn't hear you, and then they asked me what you said, I might use indirect speech and tell them, "He asked what you've been doing". This would not be me asking them a question, but me using indirect speech to inform them about the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "What you've been doing" is in form of a noun clause. For example, you can use it in the sentences that are like the following: "What you've been doing is interesting to me."

But if you want to use it as a question, you should say: "What have you been doing?"

Answer (score 0):

> What’ve you been doing?

is the correct contraction.